# How to reach Archer backend(fetch, create, update existed records) from workspace application?

Tags: rsa-archer-grc

I am trying to reach RSA Archer backend from a newly created application, for example update existed records and create new records.

As a workaround, I have tried to create Custom Object and implement a JavaScript snippet to fetch existed users by calling RSA Archer RESTful API.

Also, I also found RSA Archer blocked me (403 Forbidden Error) from creating and updating records when I was using JavaScript code in Custom Object to perform these operations.

I am wondering if RSA Archer has such integrated functionality that I can perform records manipulation (i.e fetch, update, create and delete) from the Applications, Solutions or Workspace. Any good ideas that I can connect workspace application to Archer backend would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a `POST` via the REST APIs within Archer you need to add the following header.
`'x-csrf-token': (window.sessionStorage) ? window.sessionStorage.getItem("x-csrf-token") : parent.parent.ArcherApp.globals['xCsrfToken']`

Comment: thank you for your reply! Is this how I can send a POST request INSIDE of the RSA Archer? since I am trying to send POST call using JavaScript in Custom Object. Also, do I need to specify the value of xCsrfToken or just leave it as a string? Thank you!

Comment: It depends on what way you make the REST API call, either native JavaScript or jQuery.  Nope, the line will provide the `x-csrf-token` automatically to the header.